# How to delegate permissions in Samba using command line?

Tags: samba

Is it some how possible to delegate password resetting permissions in Samba using the command line (for example using `samba-tools`)?

I want to automate the process and don't want to use the GUI wizard for this, but I could not find any helpful info to achieve this in the docs.

Just to make it clear, I want one of my domain users, let us call him *binding_user* to be able to login to Windows and use Active Directory Users and Computers tool to change the password of other users. So this user will play the role of support user, for example, who can reset the password of users who forgot their passwords (in Windows environment). This is normally possible by delegating a special permission to this user but in the a GUI app in Windows, but I want this delegation to happen somehow using the command line.

Comment: Does this help?   https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/samba-tool.8.html   ....     user password [options]    .......  Change password for a user account (the one provided in authentication).

Comment: The [smbpasswd command](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smbpasswd.8.html) can be used by normal users to change their own passwords. (Only root can change any user's password.) Does that help?

Comment: @John Please see the update

Comment: @harrymc please check the update